# Migration targets for the rest of us

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration

I'm sure ♦ mods can already do this, but it would be nice if us peons could pick migration targets like everyone with vote to close privileges can on most other SE sites.  I've seen a couple questions get closed that I think would have made great questions on other sites.

This also necessitates selecting migration targets, since they're different for every site. Look for some suggestions below the fold.

Comment: If you feel we should have a migration path to a certain site, feel free to suggest it. Keep in mind that the spots are limited (I think to four) so it'll only be the most useful paths. In the meantime, flag a post that you think should be migrated. Sklivvz, Fabian or I will take care of it.

Comment: @Borror0:  We have five on SuperUser.

Answer (score 4):

We don't add migration paths until after the site graduates from public beta.  Also, we don't add them just because a couple questions could have been migrated.  We want to see evidence that questions are being flagged and moved by moderators significantly enough that it warrants a migration path being added.

Comment: I had a feeling that was the case.  I'll leave the suggested targets for when we graduate then.  :-)

Comment: Rebecca, would you like us to review the migration paths?

Comment: @Sklivvz did you look at http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats?  No need for migration paths when nothing is getting migrated.

Answer (score 2):

### Suggested Migration Targets

- [Super User](http://www.superuser.com/)
- [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)
- [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/)
- [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/)
- [Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Historically, Physics is your highest value non-Meta target for migrations, having taken 20 migrations across the lifetime of your site. Which, isn't a high number. And to that point, there has been a single migration to Physics in the past 90 days, and only 5 within the past 365 days.

Actually, of late migrations have gone every which direction. There isn't any one dominating site within recent migrations.

As [Rebecca noted](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/865/migration-targets-for-the-rest-of-us/866#866), we don't instate migration paths unless there is shown to be a significant demand for the need of the path, by high volumes of migrations. At this time, no target site qualifies.